# Python for comprehension with dict keys and values in else clause

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, for-comprehension

Attached is my sample in below. Aim's want to update dict based on key which is present in another list. if key is present in the list update value +1 otherwise value -1. I tried with for comprehension approach and getting syntax error. through simple for loop , will solve the problem. but i am looking for approach with for comprehension.

[image]

Comment: Just drop the syntactically-invalid `key:` after `else`.  Everything between the first `key:` and `for` is part of a single expression.

Comment: What do you expect `data[key]` in `data[key]-1` to evaluate to when `key in data` is `False`?

Comment: It looks like what you actually want is `{k: v + (1 if k in list_update_keys else -1) for k, v in data.items()}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are trying to use a conditional expression in a dictionary comprehension, but you actually wanted something like:

```
{
  key: (data[key]+1 if key in data else data[key]-1)
  for key in list_update_keys
}
```

But this will result in a `KeyError` if the wide is triggered, since in that case the key is not in the dictionary.